# Duda con la salida del siguiente código (Arrays)

Tags: java, array

No entiendo la salida de este código

import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class Referencias {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        int[] a = new int[4];
        x++;

        fun(x, a);
        System.out.println(x + " " + Arrays.toString(a));

        x++;
        fun(x, a);
        System.out.println(x + " " + Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    public static void fun(int x, int[] a) {
        x++;
        a[x]++;
        System.out.println(x + " " + Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

La salida es:

```
2 [0, 0, 1, 0]
1 [0, 0, 1, 0]
3 [0, 0, 1, 1]
2 [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Creo tener claro de dónde salen la salida de las 'x' pero no entiendo los arrays.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres al tipo de datos, un array es una lista. Cada elemento del array se caracteriza por su número de orden (índice). Cada elemento puede ser de cualquier tipo de datos.
Si te refieres a este caso concreto, tienes una lista (a) de 4 numeros enteros, Incialmente todos son 0. El índice va desde 0 al 3.
Cuando llama a fun(x, a), el primer argumento es una copia de la varable x, por eso el cambio dentro de **fun** no afecta fuera de ella. El segundo argumeno es el propio array, por eso los cambios dentro de la función afectan al array también fuera de la función.

Comment: Ante todo, gracias por la respuesta. Sí, tengo claro que es un lista y sus índices y los elementos que puede contener el array. Lo que no acabo de comprender son las salidas del array que proporciona tanto las llamadas a la función como los println fuera de la función. En la primera llamada al método, según mi interpretación , tengo como argumentos x=1 y el array. El método transforma a x=2 y a[x]=3, por lo que no veo como la salida del array tiene que ser [0, 0, 1, 0]. Espero haber expuesto bien mi duda. Muchas gracias

Comment: Una vez aclarado el ámbito de la variable y de los arrays por la explicación de @Juan, mi duda estaba en la línea a[x]++. Entiendo que lo que hace es tomar la posición x del array a (en la primera salida, la posición 2) y sumarle 1 al valor de esa posición , quedando el array de esta forma [0,0,1,0].

Comment: Exact el operador++ hace eso: sumarle uno a la variable, en este caso un item del array.